# SVG not displaying in website through css

Tags: css, svg

i am trying to add an svg logo i made in inkscape appear in my website

here is the css i am using to try and display it

When i load the page nothing appears, but if i navigate through the browser to my images folder then the logo shows fine, so why is it not displaying through the css.

```
#ind_header_logo{

    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/index/logo.svg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;


}
```

EDIT: Just realised that it displays fine in firefox as well just not chrome

Comment: It's going to be hard to say anything specifically without seeing a link to the site or your file structure or something. Your code looks fine as is.

Comment: All the file structure must be fine for it to be working in firefox, its just weird why chrome is not displaying it. Unfortunately i am working on a local server, so there is no way to show you the page directly

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I know that SVG is definitely supported as a background-image on most modern browsers. In order to debug, maybe try using it as an inline svg instead to see if it works?

Comment: You could verify in the developer console that chrome is able to load (or not) the file.

Comment: Specifically, in Chrome developer tools:  check the console for error messages, check the styles on your div to confirm that it is applying the background property correctly, and check the resources tab to confirm that the svg is showing up ok as an image resource.  If none of those is the problem, post the SVG code -- Chrome and Firefox have some differences in default sizing of SVG, it could be that Chrome is rendering it but the actual graphic is being positioned outside the div (try switching to `background-size:contain;` to test that possibility).

Comment: Hi, there was no error message in the console and i checked the resource tab for images and the logo is not appearing in there. However if i add an image tag like this `<img src="/images/index/logo.svg" height="70px" width="400px"/>` in the div, then the logo appears in the resource tab but has an error saying it cannot find it. However, if i type `http://localhost/site/images/index/logo.svg` into the browser url, then the logo appears fine. Oh and `background-size:contain` does nothing different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an object like this, i know there are some disadvantages for this, but it was the only thing that worked

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/index/logo.svg">

            </object>
```